# How to plant my own code at the beginning/end of each function with GCC

Tags: c, gcc

GCC (I am using GCC-4.8.5) has the concepts of prologue and epilogue, which are used to generate codes at the beginning and end of each function. I am wondering how to insert my own code into the prologue and epilogue. I tried to search "prologue/epilogue" in the gcc source code, but still do not have any idea(I am new to compiler). Can anyone tell me how to achieve this in detail (e.g. which function in gcc shall I look for, and etc.).

Someone asked a similar question [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2000-05/msg00293.html), but the answers there were not helpful.

Comment: The "prologue" and "epilogue" are your boilerplate stack operations. The link you listed looks like they're trying to modify GCC itself. Definitely not recommended.

Comment: [`-finstrument-functions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! But what I wanna do is to manipulate a function's stack before this function exists. If using -finstrument-functions, I will not be able to access the caller's stack within __cyg_profile_func_exit(). Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you exactly want to do. Instead of changing he compiler which is a complicated job to do you may insert asm code before your function call or in your function to manipulate the compiler-implemented call mechanism. Or you may use asm code to call your function instead of using standard syntax. I remember I read about this somewhere. I think it was one of osdev.org articles.

Comment: Actually, I want to manipulate the stack of each function before it returns (e.g print out the contents of the stack). Yes, this can be achieved by adding a few lines of code at the end of each function. But it is not feasible for large project which could consist of hundereds of thousands of functions (e.g. Linux kernel). Thus I am looking for an approach to have it done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Define a new ret function and call it in your functions using return ret();. In this new ret function dump the stack.